# Rubygems: OK to have symlinks in gem distribution?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I'm a gem author. Is it OK to have symlinks in gem files, or will it break on Windows?

Comment: I think it'll likely break. Also, I'm curious, what do you need symlinks for?

Comment: @Sergio This was research for my blog post: http://www.solitr.com/blog/2012/04/contributor-friendly-gems/ I was wondering whether you can symlink files from a Git submodule into the vendor/assets directory. (Since you can't, as Joel pointed out, I'm recommending using a rake task for this.)

Comment: There is no answer to this question in term of if being possible or not, or how it works in different systems. I came here because it seems symlinks are not being included in my final distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fully specify paths, not use symlinks.

If your gems needs to find files, look at these:

```
 File.join
 Pathname
 the variable __FILE__
```

Comment: I'm not really worried about specifying/computing paths. I'm just trying to figure out whether it's enough to symlink some assets into place, or if I have to cp them.

Comment: Yes, you should copy them. Just last night I was helping a gem user diagnose this kind of issue - he was stuck because a gem tried to symlink an asset file, rather than copying it into assets/